# Can virtual memory size be larger than disk?

Tags: architecture, operating-system, virtual-memory

I have learned that virtual memory size cannot be larger than disk size since otherwise there might be a page that does not reside in the disk, needless to say, memory (*)

But, when we say the 64bit computer's virtual address space, there can be as large as 2^64 byte, which is much larger than disk size, which is a totally conflicting idea with (*)

What is the correct approach to these conflicting ideas?

Comment: `virtual memory size cannot be larger than disk size since otherwise there might be a page that does not reside in the disk` <- there are many types of pages that do not reside on disk. Look up "anonymous pages". Your statement is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conflict here - 64 bit processor indeed can address up to 2^64 bytes of memory, if available, but that does not mean that it can do this on actual present hardware where usually (:-)) less amount is available, so on concrete hardware the lowest of two (i.e. size of data which can be addressed by the processor and the actual available hardware size) will be the limiting factor.